# How can I use the latest version of the Sunspot gem with Solr Cell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, solr-cell

I've been trying (in vain) to get the latest version of the Sunspot gem (currently 2.0.0.pre.111215, incorporating Solr 3.5) working with Solr Cell.

Currently I am using the older version of Sunspot in combination with Solr Cell provided by the following plugin - https://github.com/chebyte/sunspot_cell.

My Gemfile for this configuration is as follows;

```
gem 'sunspot', '1.2.1'
gem 'sunspot_rails'
```

Unfortunately this older combination of Solr/Solr cell does not work with many newer PDF files. The recommended solution by Apache is to upgrade to the latest version of both.

The Sunspot Solr Cell bolt-on doesn't seem to be very well supported. The most recently updated version has been switched from a Plugin to a Gem, but I still can't get it to work with the latest version of the Sunspot Gem. https://github.com/zheileman/sunspot_cell

Does anyone know the correct Gemfile configuration to get the elements to play nicely together? The closest I have is this.

```
gem 'sunspot_cell', :git => 'git://github.com/zheileman/sunspot_cell.git'
gem 'sunspot', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git"
gem 'sunspot_rails', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git", :require => "sunspot_rails"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sunspot_solr', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git"
end
```

When I run any rake task I get the following error.

```
uninitialized constant Sunspot::RSolr
```

If I comment the sunspot_cell gem out temporarily, I can get Rake tasks to run but actual searching fails.

I've tried manually using the Solr jar files in [this gem](https://github.com/mrcsparker/sunspot_cell_jars) instead of the ones bundled in sunspot_solr but also without success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error, the answer to this turned out to be easier than I had hoped. The gems were apparently specified in the wrong order. I didn't realise it made any difference. I changed the order so that sunspot_cell was last and it burst into like. Magic! (almost).

```
gem 'sunspot', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git"
gem 'sunspot_rails', :git => "git://github.com/sunspot/sunspot.git", :require => "sunspot_rails"
gem 'sunspot_cell', :git => 'git://github.com/zheileman/sunspot_cell.git'
```

Answer (score 2):

Glad to know you already fixed it.
This is my current setup. A pretty big mess of gems, I know =)

```
gem 'rsolr', :git => 'git://github.com/mwmitchell/rsolr', :branch => "38b5b69a0d63cdf85560806c06f3187ea4339f5a" # 1.0.6 plus the timeout patch
gem 'sunspot'
gem 'sunspot_solr'
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_index_queue'
gem 'sunspot_cell', :git => 'git://github.com/zheileman/sunspot_cell.git', :branch => "bc8ac18de1410b3e29af89c4d028acc6deba1e1c"
```